# No definition found for class:'com.subbu.unittestsample.TestUtil2'. Check your definitions

Tags: android, junit, koin, android-koin

I am trying to write a unit test cases for one of the KoinComponent class but I am getting the below error

```
org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'com.subbu.unittestsample.TestUtil2'. Check your definitions!
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.throwDefinitionNotFound(Scope.kt:264)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:233)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:204)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at com.subbu.unittestsample.TestUtil$special$$inlined$inject$default$1.invoke(KoinComponent.kt:74)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at com.subbu.unittestsample.TestUtil$Companion.getTest2(TestUtil.kt:12)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at com.subbu.unittestsample.TestUtil$Companion.test(TestUtil.kt:21)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at com.subbu.unittestsample.ExampleInstrumentedTest.koinTest(ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt:48)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:162)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:67)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:446)
11-13 11:06:14.886 10707 10726 E TestRunner:    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
11-13 11:06:14.887 10707 10726 E TestRunner: ----- end exception -----
```

TestUtil2.kt

```
class TestUtil2 : KoinComponent,ITestUtil2 {
    override fun getMsg(): String {
        return "TestUtil2 print"
    }
}

interface ITestUtil2 {
    fun getMsg():String
}
```

Unit test class

```
@Test
    fun koinTest() {
        startKoin {
            module {
                single<ITestUtil2> { TestUtil2() }
                single { TestUtil() }
            }
        }

        val test = TestUtil.test(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
        println("Subbu $test")
    }
```

TestUtil1.kt

```
class TestUtil: KoinComponent {
    companion object:KoinComponent {
        private val test2:TestUtil2 by inject()
        fun test(context:Context): String? {
            println("Subbu ${test2.getMsg()}")
            return string
        }
    }
}
```